# How can I export a table from a .db file in SQL to Excel and csv

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to extract a table that I created in SQLite to a csv and excel file?

My table is created but I am struggling with the commands to export just the table that I created to a csv and xls file.

Comment: Google "sqlite export table to csv" and check the first result, is a step-by-step tutorial. (http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-export-csv/)

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_export